# Arg min with two 'input'

Tags: linear-algebra, elementary-set-theory

I have a question concerning the arg min operator. I know how it works for a single 'input' (i.e. input for which the function attains its minimal value), but can it have two inputs? If I have a matrix D, $\mathcal{D}$, X and A, and I have the following equation

$\text{arg min}_{D \in \mathcal{D}, A} ||X-DA||^2_F + \lambda\Omega(A)$,

Does this mean that arg min has two inputs, one for $D \in \mathcal{D}$ and one for the matrix A, or is $D \in \mathcal{D}$ and $D \in A$?

And as a side question, what does the F in $||X-DA||^2_F$ mean when it is subscripted like that? The paper I have it from does not mention anything about F, so I figure there is some basic math knowledge I am missing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I read it is to find the minimum of your expression when $D\in\mathcal D$ and $A$ is unrestricted (your first interpretation). $F$ should be Frobenius norm, but without looking at the paper it's impossible to be sure.

Comment: Thanks! The paper is 'Learning Word Representations with Hierarchical Sparse Coding' and the equation can be seen on page 2 (Equation 1)

Comment: I looked at the paper and I can confirm that $\lVert\cdot\rVert_F$ is the Frobenius norm.

Comment: Thank you so much. I have somehow managed to confuse myself. The 2 in $||X-DA||^2_F$, it is something like matrix L2 norm? Or am I missing something again?

Comment: The $2$ means that the norm is squared.